# mongodb aggregation $match on date not giving expected results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregation:

```
{   
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$key",
        "temp": {"$last": "$temp"},
        "name": {"$last": "$name"},
        "ts": {"$last": "$ts"},
        "maxTemp": {"$max": "$temp"},
        "minTemp": {"$min": "$temp"}
    }
}
```

that gives me this result:

```
[
    {"_id":"bedroom","temp":21.875,"name":"Bedroom","ts":"2017-04-30T08:33:44.789Z","maxTemp":24.875,"minTemp":21.437},
    {"_id":"livingRoom","temp":18.812,"name":"Living Room","ts":"2017-04-30T08:24:40.126Z","maxTemp":19.625,"minTemp":17.625}
]
```

but I want to limit this to the last 24 hours so I alter it as follows:

```
let now = new Date();
let yesterday = new Date(now.getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "ts": {$gte: yesterday}
        }
    },
    {   
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$key",
            "temp": {"$last": "$temp"},
            "name": {"$last": "$name"},
            "ts": {"$last": "$ts"},
            "maxTemp": {"$max": "$temp"},
            "minTemp": {"$min": "$temp"}
        }
    }
]
```

and I get these results:

```
[
    {"_id":"livingRoom","temp":18.75,"name":"Living Room","ts":"2017-04-30T08:06:41.000Z","maxTemp":19.625,"minTemp":17.625},
    {"_id":"bedroom","temp":21.875,"name":"Bedroom","ts":"2017-04-30T08:24:04.000Z","maxTemp":23.812,"minTemp":21.437}
]
```

The ts of the last record has changed. The match should only affect the min and max values, not the timestamp of the last value but the match seems to be filtering out more recent records than records further in the past.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is the comparison of the dates. Modifying it as follows works:

```
let now = new Date();
let yesterday = new Date(now.getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "ts": {$gte: yesterday.toISOString()}
        }
    },
    {   
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$key",
            "temp": {"$last": "$temp"},
            "name": {"$last": "$name"},
            "ts": {"$last": "$ts"},
            "maxTemp": {"$max": "$temp"},
            "minTemp": {"$min": "$temp"}
        }
    }
]
```